# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on a sequelize constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, sequelize.js

I have a discord.js bot that works perfectly on my Windows machine. When I run it on my raspberry pi, I get a Segmentation fault. I have narrowed it down to this one line of code:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  logging: false,
  storage: 'database.sqlite',
});
```

I don't understand how this could work on my Windows computer but not my raspberry pi. Node.js, all node modules and my raspberry pi are all up to date.

Comment: You might be able to debug with https://www.npmjs.com/package/segfault-handler

Comment: It spit out `
PID 2379 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x3ceae84
/home/caelb/Desktop/discordbot/greenbot2/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x2570)[0x762ed570]
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__default_rt_sa_restorer+0x0)[0x76b32db0]
`

Comment: Is that the only line? If not, post all of it as an edit into your question.